# subdomain with additional catalog to variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard

I need to transform this:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page
```

to

```
domain.com/site.php?site=subdomain&page=page
```

Here is part of my code without page variable:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$
RewriteRule .* site.php?site=%1
```

How to pass page variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site.php?site=%1&page=$1 [L]
```

The first rule prevents both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` from getting redirected.

Comment: Thanks for answer but now value of page is always "site.php".

Comment: @user1768403 Glad it helped. +1 for the question.